# object of abstract class type "QuarterBack" is not allowed

Tags: c++

I have an abstract base class called Player, and it has a subclass called QuarterBack. If I try to instantiate an object of QuarterBack, then I receive 2 errors stating: a) object of abstract class type "QuarterBack" is not allowed: b)'QuarterBack': cannot instantiate abstract class

There are two pure virtual functions in Player called getPlayerPosition() and play(). However, I am only getting an error for getPlayerPosition() Quarter back is supposed to be the concrete subclass to Player, but the compiler says that QuarterBack is still an abstract class.

I don't know where to start fixing these errors.

```
class Player {
private: 
string fname, lname, position;
int playerID;
static int numPlayers;
public:
Player(string fname, string lname, string position, int playerID) {
    this->fname = fname;
    this->lname = lname;
    this->position = position;
    this->playerID = playerID;
    ++numPlayers;
    cout << "Creating Player" << endl;
}
~Player() {
    cout << "Destroying Player" << endl;
}

string getName() {
    return fname + " " + lname;
}

virtual string getPlayerPosistion() = 0; // pure virtual function

virtual int play() = 0; // pure virtual function

string toString() {
    string temp = "Name: " + fname + " " + lname + " | Position: " + position + " | Number: " + to_string(playerID);
    return temp;
}
};


class QuarterBack : public Player {
private:
string fname, lname, position;
int playerID;
public:
QuarterBack(string fname, string lname, string position, int playerID) : Player(fname, lname, position, playerID) {
    this->fname = fname;
    this->lname = lname;
    this->position = position;
    this->playerID = playerID;
    cout << "Creating QuarterBack " << endl;

}
~QuarterBack() {
    cout << "Destroying QuarterBack" << endl;
}

string getName() {
    return fname + " " + lname;
}

string getPlayerPosition() {
    return position;
}

int play() {
    return 0;
}
};

int main()
{
string firstN, lastN, position;
int ID;
firstN = "Tom";
lastN = "Johnson";
position = "QuarterBack";
ID = 17;
QuarterBack qb(firstN, lastN, position, ID);
cout << qb.toString() << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a typo in function name getPlayerPosistion

Comment: Typo. The function name is spelled `getPlayerPosistion` in the base class while it is spelled `getPlayerPosition` in the derived class. There's an extra `s` in the name in the base class. Voting to close for typo.

Comment: Oh man I was getting so frustrated. Thanks man, it works without the typo

Comment: From now on, consider using the `override` specifier when you are intentionally overloading a virtual method. It will emit an error if it doesn't actually override something.